# Apache - почему при одновременном исп. в .htaccess базовой аутентификации и mod_rewrite ошибку получаю

Tags: .htaccess, apache, битрикс, apache2

В корневой директории сайта, создан симлинк

xhprof_html -> /usr/share/php/xhprof_html

и мне нужно что бы при обращении по url
http://xhprof.admin.fvds.ru была переадресация на
/home/bitrix/ext_www/xhprof.admin.fvds.ru/xhprof_html

также нужно что бы была базовая аутентификация

В .htaccess пишу такие директивы

```
AuthType Basic

AuthName "Restricted Files"

# (Following line optional)

AuthBasicProvider file

AuthUserFile "/home/bitrix/ext_www/xhprof.admin.fvds.ru/.htpasswd"

Require user admin


<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>

 Options +FollowSymLinksi

 RewriteEngine On

 RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f

 RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-l

 RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d

 RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !/xhprof_html/index.php$

 RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /xhprof_html/index.php [L]

</IfModule>
```

но они приводят к ошибке

> Internal Server Error The server encountered an internal error or
> misconfiguration and was unable to complete your request.
>
> Please contact the server administrator at webmaster@localhost to
> inform them of the time this error occurred, and the actions you
> performed just before this error.
>
> More information about this error may be available in the server error
> log.
>
> Apache Server at xhprof.admin65.fvds.ru Port 80

тут нет ничего

```
tail -200 /var/log/httpd/access_log
```

ту тоже

```
tail -200 /var/log/httpd/error_log
```

Эти директивы работают только по отдельности но не вместе! Т.е или переадресация или редирект, но вместе не хотят...

Как понять, в чем проблема?

Comment: FollowSymLinksi